# Post request with dynamic variables

Tags: angular, typescript, post, dynamic

I would like to do a post dynamic post request, the request can have a maximum of 5 parameters but can have less aswell.

My issue here is that I can't find a way to send those dynamics variable, I've tried using a forEach loop that will check each parameters but with no success.

Here's an example of the params I want to send, `country_id` & `user_id` are both arrays cause the user can select multiple people/countries, 2 & 3 and string both for a name.

*this.filtersArray picture*

[image]

My array contains the values I need to send but the APi needs to receive them with the params "country_id", "user_id", "title", "code" and that's where I'm struggling cause I don't know how to make those parameters variables of my url.

Example :

I have only the params "title","code","country_id", how do I make my http post not send "user_id" aswell ?

**component.ts**

```
  sendFilter() {
    this.filtersArray.forEach((item, i, array) => {
      console.log(item, i, array);
    });
    return this.httpClient.get<ProjectInterface>(this.myUrl, {

    });*/
  }
```

How do I make it call and send the variables that have a value only ?

Thank's for your time in advance, don't hesitate to tell me if you need more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` function on array to check whether the `length` property of the property in your `Object` is greater than 0. Both `Array` and `String` have the length property hence this can be used

See Below sample

```js
const initialData = {
    country_id: [1, 2],
    user_id: [],
    title: 'Some Nice Title',
    code: 'gfrhfhhhfrgde',
}

const finalData = Object.entries(initialData).reduce((prev, next) => 
 (next[1]?.length > 0) ? ({ ...prev, [next[0]]: next[1]}) : prev, {})

console.log(finalData)
```